# Call a javaScript function with arguments in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function with arguments that I want to call in jQuery and I am stuck.

I tried this : 
$("a").click(highlight(arg))
but it doesnt work.

Any ideas ?

Johanna

Comment: What do you mean you want to call it "in jQuery?" Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    highlight(arg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(highlight);
```

that would be a total bypass.

otherwise:
eg. if you need a specific property of `event`

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    highlight(event.specialProp);
});
```

otherwise:
eg. if you declared `args` yourself

```
var args = 'demoArgs';
$('a').click(function() {
    higlhight(args);
});
```